# Disabling proxy repositories in Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm setting up a new small Nexus OSS server on an Amazon EC2 instance. Nexus ships with proxies set up for the Apache, Central, and Codehaus repositories, assuming that the Nexus server will be local to the users. Since the Nexus server is at least as far away as the other repositories, I'd rather not pay to send all of my artifacts through it (and for it to be constantly updating indexes). What's the best way to stop Nexus from proxying external repositories--should I just delete the entries for them, or will that break other things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use this Nexus to host only your private repositories, and the devs team have properly configured maven locally to use it *only* for that repo, all you need to do is open
the `Repositories` tab, right-click on the repository you want to disable, and select `Put Out of Service`.

[image]

Comment: I was hoping that would do it, but it's not immediately obvious what the option means. Thanks!